# Absolute Positioning with Footer not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, position, footer

I have no idea how to fix this.
Putting things on position: relative will null out the bottom: 0px, and will also create tons of white space on pages that don't fit the entire height due to lack of content.

Putting it on absolute makes it cover content of pages that do have content long enough to generate a scroll bar.

```
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #3167b1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

This should be working right? For some reason it just doesn't. Is it Wordpress? Never had this problem before and I have already gone through and cleaned up a lot of issues that may have caused it.

EDIT:
Silly me... I forgot the html here.
Right now it has nothing in it so it is just:

```
<div class="footer"></div>
```

I have it like that just to test it.
To see what is happening you can visit it here:
http://www.yenrac.net/theme

I hope that helps clarify some things.

I have also created this theme from scratch.

Comment: Please also post your html. Otherwise I guess you need to specify margin-bottom for the body container equal or more than the height of your footer.

Comment: It's actually working as it should. The problem is that when divs are absolute, they appear ontop of normal body content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I got your question right, this should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/9qq1dtuf/

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin-bottom: 170px;
}
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #3167b1;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px; left: 0;
}
```

Comment: That sort of worked. It took it to the bottom of the page, however it is still covering content and doesn't seem to like the margin-top or bottom.

EDIT: Nevermind this worked perfectly even though I tried it before. Guess staying up all night can lead to these things >_>
Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me. My footer was previously appearing in the middle of the page, obstructing the other elements when I had the position as absolute, bottom 0px. Can anyone tell me why this works? Thank you.

Comment: This is an old answer so I think I would give a small update on it.
In 2023, "100%" doesn't work anymore with wordpress. It requires to use either "100vh" for height or "100vw" for width which wordpress recognise as "value of height" and "value of width".

Answer (score 0):

Please try bellow css

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 150px;
  background: #3167b1;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='footer'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I doubt it's Wordpress ...unless you are using a pre-made theme (*or something along those lines*).  It's pretty hard to see what you've done without seeing the HTML.  But anyways, heres what I think might have been the problem:

You have selected the footer element that has a class of "`footer`".  I'm going to go ahead and make an educated guess that you meant to select the `footer` element by its name (*NOT it's class*).  So maybe it's just a small little tiny bitty fix (*i.e. remove the "." before footer in your CSS*):

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #3167b1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to clarify the html. It's just a plain <div class="footer"></div> at the moment for testing purposes.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this to your css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #efefef;
    font-family: 'Lato', serif;
    padding-bottom: 174px; //add this line - height of footer + margin from content
}
```

I added 24px margin from content as an example. It would be best if you added this to your css:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

or just for the body

```
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

So as your added padding does not add to your height and you get unnecessary scroll-bars.