# Footer adaptative positioning with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a simple layout:

```
+----------+
|  Header  |
+----------+
|          |
| Content  |
|          |
+----------+
|  Footer  |
+----------+
```

I'd like the footer to be:

- at the bottom of the viewport when the content is not filling up all the remaining viewport space,
- under the content, outside the viewport, reachable by scrolling, if the content is filling all the viewport space or more.

Said in another manner I'd like **the content to take *at least* all the space left out by the header and the footer, and more if necessary, pushing the footer outside the viewport**.

To add to the equation I'd like to **not hard-code the height of the footer** as I guess its content's size could vary depending on the browser/device.

If I naively let the default behavior it's perfect when the content is long but when not the footer is too high on the page.

If I try to fix the footer by positioning it absolutely at the bottom it's the other way around: perfect when the content is short but it overlaps with the content when this one is too long.

I've seen and played with some "naive" (hard-coded footer's height) samples without Bootstrap: [Absolute Positioning with Footer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278664/absolute-positioning-with-footer-not-working)

Even them were not working because Bootstrap is "messing things up".
After playing with my sample I've found that the culprit is the `relative` `position` applied to all `container-fluid`.
By removing it I get the expected behavior in the "naive" case with hard-coded footer height.

So how to obtain the expected behavior with Bootstrap:

- at least in the naive case,
- without hardcoding the footer height (probably need some JS)?

```css
/*.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}*/
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-12">
                Header<br/>
                Header<br/>
                Header<br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-12">
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
                Content<br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row footer">
            <div class="col-xl-12">
                Footer<br/>
                Footer<br/>
                Footer<br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following styles to your footer:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

There's a working example from Bootstrap 4 right here: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/ The container between the navbar and the footer has `position: relative;` too, so you shouldn't have any issues with it.

Comment: Thanks, but this style is what I've specified in my question and though it's perfect when there is room in the viewport it won't work when there is none. +1 anyway because this is a part of the anwser. :)

Comment: Are you sure? I've used it on some sites myself and it works exactly like you described: stays in the bottom even if there's extra room, and goes to the (scrollable) bottom of the page when the content overflows the window. Look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5mrjebm/), for example. It's the exact same setup, except that I duplicated the content to make it scrollable. As you see, the footer goes down to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Indeed this fiddle has all the necessary parts.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this multiple times before and to be honest as a back-end developer it's always a hazard. There is one trick that does it everytime for me that somebody from my company tought me. You need to wrap all your content in a new container/wrapper, except for the footer, and then do something like this (this is copy pasted from a working example I created a couple of years ago).

```
footer {
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    margin-bottom:0;
    position: relative;
}

footer .row, footer > .row > .col-lg-12 {
    height: 75px;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;

    margin: 0 auto -75px;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
}

#container:after {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        content: "";
        height: 75px;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="container"> 

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <div id="logo" ></div>
              <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost" style="color:white">Trapetaf.be</a></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="{{ Request::is( 'history') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{URL::to('history')}}">History</a></li>
                <li class="{{ Request::is( 'leaderboard') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{URL::to('leaderboard')}}">Leaderboard</a></li>
                <li class="{{Request::is('challenges/*')  ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{URL::to('challenges')}}">Challenges</a></li>
                <li class="{{Request::is('statistics*')? 'active': ''}}"><a href="{{URL::to('statistics')}}">Statistics</a></li>
                <li class="{{ Request::is( 'login*') || Request::is('aanmelden*') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{URL::to('login')}}" >Inloggen</a></li>
                   @if(Auth::check())
                    <li class="{{ Request::is( 'admin*') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{URL::to('admin')}}">Admin</a></li>
                 @endif
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container -->
        </nav>

 @yield('content')

</div>

      <footer>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
           <p> &copy; <?php echo Date('Y')?> Trapetaf.be</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't adapt it to my use-case. Anyway +1 as there is almost all the CSS black-magic needed. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your anwsers.

I've finally come to the expected behavior by:

- setting `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0px` for the `footer`,
- setting `position: relative` for the `html` (I guess so that the `footer` is positioned relatively to it),
- setting `min-height: 100%` for the `html` (this is the one I consider black-magic),
- dynamically setting the `bottom-margin` of the body to the height of the `footer`:
  `document.body.style.marginBottom = footer.clientHeight + "px";`

I know I'm far from a genius but all this CSS stuff is beyond me. :'(

Answer (score 1):

Because flexbox is default in Bootstrap 4, this "sticky" footer is easy using flexbox..

```
<wrapper class="d-flex flex-column">
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <main>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</wrapper>

body, wrapper {
   min-height:100vh;
}

main {
    flex:1;
}
```

Demo: [Bootstrap 4 Sticky Footer with Flexbox](http://www.codeply.com/go/tGamlWscIB)